# SQL запрос в RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, запрос, sql

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь изучать реилс и столкнулся с такой проблемкой:

Есть таблица "products" в ней строки (`id`, `title`, `price`)

Вот я хочу чтоб на экран выводились самые дорогие товары (начиная с самых дорогих)

и в контроллере `store_controller.rb` (`class StoreController < ApplicationController`)

```
  def index
    @products = Product.order("price DESC")
  end
```

и во `views/store/index.html.erb`

```
<% @products.sort_by(&:price).each do |product| %>
    <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
    ....

<% end %>
```

По идее, при написании `DESC` - одна сортировка, `ASC` - другая (снизу и сверху), но меняя `DESC` на `ASC` отображение не меняется, - как было так и осталось.

а вот если меняю во Вьюхе =>

```
<% @products.sort_by(&:price).each do |product| %>
```

то работает как надо - но `sort_by` мне не нравится ->через `order` надо.

А в консоле когда тоже самое делаю (выборку по ордер) выдает :

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY title, price DESC
```

Откуда появился "`title`" ? И как это проверить?

Просто код довольно большой - и тут выложить не могу все переменные и классы, методы..

Apd. да и вот тлько что заметил что во всех запросах в консоли у меня происходит дописывание "ORDER BY title" - мб где-то дефолтно поставил добавление этой строки ( и сразу вопрос -если такое возможно поставить -то где? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Default scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope).

Вы уже определитесь, где вы сортируете, в SQL'е или в шаблоне. Правильнее, конечно, в SQL: подумайте о многостраничности (will_paginate).

Comment: да я только начинаю изучать реилс - и то где правильно сортировать учусь по книжкам ( так как не у кого спросить ) - вот и вставляю в код то, что где-то видел или слышал 
Спасибо за ответ =)

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере делайте запрос

```
@products = Product.order(price: :desc)
```

он запросит из БД продукты, упорядоченные по price по убыванию.

Код вашей вьюхи сортирует объекты, переданные из контроллера, по возрастанию, поэтому ничего и не менялось